# Bulk Actions Log

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.3.3, bulk

After testing Rest Async-Calls with `RabbitMQ-Server`, all worked fine.

In the Magento-Database the table `"magento_bulk"` and `"magento_operation"` is full with data from the Rest Async-Calls.

But in the **Magento 2.3.3** Backend "`System - Action Logs - Bulk Actions`" nothing is shown there?

**Is it possible to show the data from database there?**

Comment: Have you been able to get it working? Has it improved performance? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294027/rabbitmq-open-source-edition-case-study-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer only shows a possible solution to the problem.
>
> **Changes must be made in a separate module.**
>
> **Changes made to the Magento core files will be lost after the Magento upgrade.**

In order to display all entries in the `Bulk Actions Log`, you need to remove the selection by `user_id` in `vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations/Ui/Component/DataProvider/SearchResult.php`:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    $this->getSelect()->from(
        ['main_table' => $this->getMainTable()],
        [
            '*',
            'status' => $this->calculatedStatusSql->get($this->getTable('magento_operation'))
        ]
    )/*->where(
        'user_id=?',
        $this->userContext->getUserId()
    )*/;
    return $this;
}
```

> Link to a similar [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25371) on github.

Comment: Just saw that Magento checks internally the "user_id" (Magento Backend) with the "integration user id" (Rest-Api-Key User).